# ASP.NET Web.Config ConfigurationManager.AppSettings File Caching

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-config, configurationmanager

I am using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings collection to retreive configuration values from a Web.config file in an ASP.NET application. Does anyone know if values in AppSettings get cached in memory somehow or if a file read of Web.config occurs every time when retrieving a setting?

```
string someValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeSetting"];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are taken from memory, since the web.config is read only once when the application starts.

However, ASP.NET monitors the web.config file to detect and load changes

> It is important to realize that the entire  section is read, parsed, and cached the first time we retrieve a setting value. From that point forward, all requests for setting values come from an in-memory cache, so access is quite fast and doesn't incur any subsequent overhead for accessing the file or parsing the XML.

[Application Configuration Files Explained in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478432.aspx)

For more info:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/01/15/web-config-is-cached.aspx

Comment: That's what I was assuming but wanted to check. Exactly what I needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: This article suggests caching them still speeds things up http://www.dotnetperls.com/appsettings-cache